# Code seems to be instantiating an unimplemented interface

Tags: java, interface

I've read a few questions about instantiating an interface, but either none of them addressed my question, or else I didn't fully understand what was happening.

```
Observer observer = (Observer) observers.elementAt(i);
```

I've never encountered a statement like this. Looks like a weird way of instantiating an object. However, `Observer` is an `interface`, and the class that this statement is made in (class is `abstract`, if that has any bearing) doesn't implement the `interface`.

Could anyone explain to me what exactly is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement is retrieving an object from some sort of collection.  The object is explicitly cast to the type `Observer` and assigned to `observer` variable.  The object is not being instantiated, just retrieved.  The explicit cast makes this statement slightly dangerous because there is no way to guarantee the object retrieved from the collection implements `Observer`.

Comment: You say the statement is retrieving the object from sort of collection? I assume you are making that call from the  `observers.elementAt(i)`? The example is using `Vector` (I know it's Obsolete, I'm just trying to follow some code and see what's happening). I'm not sure I understand how an object isn't being instantiated. I thought it is creating a variable of type observer,

Comment: therefore it's being instantiated no?

I have never encountered casting before. From what I understand from what you are saying and what I have read it is creating a variable of type observer, and then casting this to type observer? or is it casting what it is pulling from the collection to type observer?

Comment: Yes at some point an object is being instantiated and placed into the vector, but its of some other type than observer.  However, that type does implement the observer interface or well hopefully since there is no guarantee the item in the vector implements the observer interface.

Comment: OK, I think I'm starting to understand you now. How can the objects be cast to type observer if there isn't an observer class?

Comment: There is an observer interface and an object can be cast to an interface.

Comment: Cool, I understand now, thanks so much for your help! On a side note, if you can cast an object to an interface, can you instantiate and interface?

Comment: You can never instantiate an interface.  You can only instantiate objects that implement an interface.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it doesn't instantiate anything, it just grabs an instance of some implementation of `Observer` from a collection (I assume it's `Vector` by the method name).

So this is what's going on

```
Vector observers = new Vector();
observers.add(new ObserverImpl());
Observer o = (Observer) observers.elementAt(0);
```

Note that this a very oldschool way of doing things, you shouldn't use `Vector` anymore and you should always use generics, so this code should be rewritten as

```
List<Observer> observers = new ArrayList<>();
observers.add(new ObserverImpl());
Observer o = observers.get(0); //you don't need to cast anymore because of generics
```

Answer (score 0):

An interface is a type of contract that ensures that the methods defined on that interface is implemented.  If an object implements an interface it has to have to cater for all the methods defined on it.

In your code example an object is cast to a variable of type `Observer` which means you can call any of the Observer methods.  It does not change the object, nor is it instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, an abstract class is a class who can't be instantiated, sometimes there is only one method abstract, sometimes the whole class is abstract. You'll have to `extend` such a class. It allows you to implement functionality in a base class.

An interface is a contract for a class and is implemented by the keyword `implements`. It Provides you the method calls, there is no functionallity in interfaces.

Now to your question:

```
Observer observer = (Observer) observers.elementAt(i);
```

This ensures an object ( containing methods like: equals, hashCode or toString) has the methods of an interface.

ex in pseudocode:

```
interface Printable{
 String print();
}
```

and its "implementation":

```
public class MyDocument implements Printable{

@Override
public String print(){
 // do the print thing
}

public void additionalMethod(){
 // do some other stuff
}
}
```

and its use

```
Printable doc = new MyDocument(); // now we ensure that we can call .print()
```

Answer (score 0):

An interface is a contract to its implementing classes. It is perfectly legal to write a code that you encountered . 
Lets understand this with a simple example :

create an interface Animal

```
public interface Animal {
    public void eat();
}
```

create two implementing classes as Horse and Cat that implements this interface.

```
public class Cat implements Animal {
    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("Cat eats Mouse.");
    }
}

public class Horse implements Animal {
    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("Horse eats hay.");
    }
}
```

Now test the behavior using a Tesy class :

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Horse h = new Horse();
        Cat c = new Cat();
        Animal a =  (Animal)h;
        a.eat();
        a = (Animal)c;
        a.eat();
    }
}
```

The output would be :

```
Horse eats hay.
Cat eats Mouse.
```

This kind of behavior supports dynamic polymorphism or run time polymorphism.
Even though you have the reference of Animal object you hold the objects of Horse or Cat which implements the methods so you can call them. An Animal reference holding the object of class that implements it can call only those methods which are declared in the interface Animal.